# Linked List with Comparison

Tags: java

Hello I need to implement a Hashtable with a separate chaining. For that I am implementing a Node class and LinkedList. Nodes included in the linked list have the attributes data, count, a link to next and a link to previous.Linked list should not have values with duplicate value but given another node with the same value inserted, the count of that node should be increased. Above is my code but I could not figure out on how to implement the insert function so that when a duplicate node is found, the count is increased.

```
public void insertToHead(Node newNode) {
    newNode.setNext(head);
    head = newNode;
}

public void drop(Node newNode) {
    newNode.getPrev().setNext(newNode.getNext());
}

public void insert(String newData) {
    Node newNode = new Node(newData);
    Node temp = head;
    if (temp == null) {
        insertToHead(newNode);
        newNode.incrementCount();
        nodeCount++;
    } else {
        for(int i=0;i<nodeCount;i++){
            if(temp.getData().equals(newNode.getData())){
                if(temp.getPrev()==null){
                    temp.incrementCount();
                    head=temp;
                }
                if(temp.getNext()==null){
                     temp.getPrev().setNext(null);
                    temp.incrementCount();
                    insertToHead(temp);
                }
                else{
                temp.incrementCount();
                drop(temp);
                insertToHead(temp);
                }
            }
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        insertToHead(newNode);
        nodeCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(temp==){` will not compile!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, was my mistake but still not working as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse the linked list until you found an equal node and then increment the count on the same node, not the previous. If you reached the end of the list in that process, you do your normal insertion.

```
Node newNode = new Node(newData);
Node temp = head;
if (temp == null) {
    insertToHead(newNode);
    newNode.incrementCount();
    nodeCount++;
} else {
   while(temp != null){
      if(temp.getData().equals(newNode.getData())){
        temp.incrementCount();
        break;
      }
      temp = temp.getNext();
   }

   // didn't find anything, prepend to the list
   if(temp == null){
    insertToHead(newNode);
    nodeCount++;
   }
}
```